# JQuery ajax php post problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

This may sound strange but I have a JQ/AJAX/PHP post problem.

My "code" is all there and works in most situations except 1 - when I try to pass a  tag through the process.

I grab the html like this

```
var ed = $('#fraRTE').contents().find('body #editarea').html();
```

`#fraRTE` is an iframe width an editable div `#editarea` hence `.contents().find('body #editarea').html()`

So if `var ed` is just "hello world etc...." there is no problem and the data is processed BUT if `var ed` is something like "hello world etc.... `<img src="image.png">`" the data is not processed - stangely if `var ed` is "hello world etc....`<img src="image.png">`" - no gap between text and the image the data is actually processed.

If I `alert(ed)` before the post then I see the "correct" string - whatever it's contents, post like this:

```
var data = 'content='+ed;
$.ajax({ 
type: 'post', 
url:  'script.php',
data: data,
success: function(msg) { 
alert(msg);
}
```

});

I create the data string before "data:data" as there are a few more items in the string.

my `alert(msg)` is set by `echo $_POST['content'];` on `script.php`

the alert(msg) tells me what has (or has not) been posted to the DB. this is where I see the problem mentioned above. i.e. the inclusion (or not) of `<img...>`

Suggestions please

Comment: `var data = 'content='+ed;` - better use `var data = {content: ed};`

Comment: @ThiefMaster - sorry but why? - i'm still newish at JQ that's all

Comment: It ensures you don't have to take care about special characters like `&` in your data - jQuery will serialize the array into a properly encoded string for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is smart enough to handle turning your request data into a query string for you.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post', 
  url:  'script.php',
  data: { content: ed },
  success: function(msg) { 
    alert(msg);
  }
});
```

This issue you are having is the data not being properly escaped.

In order to stringify it yourself, you would have to use `encodeURIComponent()`

```
"content=" + encodeURIComponent(ed);
```

But it's far simpler to just let jQuery do it for you.

Comment: { content: ed } - didn't work for me but "content=" + encodeURIComponent(ed); is perfect.

Comment: It should work.  Look at the actual request hitting your PHP page and see what is in the query string.  Assuming `ed` is just a string then `{content:ed}` will work, I promise.  Encoding this yourself would be "doing it wrong".

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string concatenations when constructing request parameters or they won't be properly url encoded and if the parameter contains some special characters it won't be properly received. Here's the correct way:

```
var data = { content: ed };
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'post', 
    url:  'script.php',
    data: data,
    success: function(msg) { 
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```